# React Native - "You are currently using minified code outside of NODE_ENV === "production" "

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, expo

I'm getting this error with React Native, not ReactJS so all the solutions/workarounds with webpack or browserify wont help.

Full error:

> You are currently using minified code outside of NODE_ENV=== "production". This means that you are running a slower development build of Redux. You can use ... bla bla bla ( workarounds for ReactJS )

I'm currently running this config :

```
"expo": "^23.0.0",
"react": "16.0.0",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-23.0.0.tar.gz",
"react-redux": "^5.0.6",
"redux": "^3.7.2"
```

I tried starting the service with `--no-minify` and I always start it with `--dev`. I'm running the app on `expo` as well.

If anyone has a solution or a workaround for this it'd be really appreciated.

Answer (score 13):

If you're running into this issue while using an android virtual device, open the debug menu (CMD+M on a Mac) > Dev Settings -> Uncheck JS Minify and reload your app. Pictures included below for reference.

[image: Debug Menu]

[image: AVD Settings]