# React Native - You are currently using minified code outside of NODE_ENV === "production"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, expo

I am getting following error:

You are currently using minified code outside of NODE_ENV === "production". error in React Native app after adding redux to my project.

Screenshots : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1RjU.jpg

I tried this - [React Native - "You are currently using minified code outside of NODE_ENV === "production" "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50608294/react-native-you-are-currently-using-minified-code-outside-of-node-env-p) but I am not getting the last 'Dev Settings' option in my popup.

I tried many options from the internet but nothing seems to work.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Validate:

1. Package.json scripts:

   ```
     "scripts": {
       "start": "expo start",
     "android": "expo start --android",
      "ios": "expo start --ios",
     "eject": "expo eject"
    },
   ```

2.".expo"   directory=>settings.json

```
{
  "hostType": "lan",
  "lanType": "ip",
  "dev": true,
  "minify": false,
  "urlRandomness": "zt-j39"
}
```

run: expo start